# 504 Gateway error nginx due to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

When I try to execute nested for loop to insert data into mysql table I get 504 Gateway error - Nginx. How do you think I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Please make sure your config file of the server is configured correctly. That is usually the most common problem.

Comment: Which file you are talking about? Nginx.conf or mysql ?

Comment: Whatever config file you are using to set up the server

Comment: That is my question. What do I need to configure ? What variables I need to set and in which file ?

Comment: Well when you set up the server did you not configure anything?

Comment: I used Plesk 12.5 to setup everything.